# multiply two text file in VHDL

Tags: file, vhdl

I have two text file in VHDL that have 1000 lines. each line contains a floating point for example 0.1234. I want to multiply each line in two text file and create a new text file. for example multiply two floating point in line 1001 and write the result in line of 1001 of new text file. my code is here but it is incorrect.

```
entity file_io is  -- test bench
end file_io;
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;
use STD.textio.all;

architecture test of file_io is
  file file_VECTORS1 : text;
  file file_VECTORS2 : text;
  file file_RESULTS1 : text;
  file file_RESULTS2 : text;
  file file_RESULTS3 : text;
  --signal dataread1 : integer;
  --signal dataread2 : integer;
  signal d1,d2 : integer;
  --signal aa : integer;
begin
  read_file:
    process    
    variable v_ILINE1    : line;
    variable aa             : line;
    variable v_ILINE2     : line; 
    variable dataread1 : integer;
    variable dataread2 : integer;

    begin
    file_open(file_VECTORS1, "a.txt",  read_mode);
    file_open(file_RESULTS1, "b.txt", write_mode);
    file_open(file_VECTORS2, "c.txt",  read_mode);
    file_open(file_RESULTS2, "d.txt", write_mode);
    file_open(file_RESULTS3, "e.txt", write_mode);

   while not endfile(file_VECTORS1) loop
      readline(file_VECTORS1, v_ILINE1);
      readline(file_VECTORS2, v_ILINE2);
      ---------------------------------------------------------------------
      read(v_ILINE1, dataread1);
      read(v_ILINE2, dataread2);
      d1 <= dataread1;
      d2 <= dataread2;
      aa <= (d1 * d2);
     writeline(file_RESULTS3, aa);
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------
      wait for 60 ns;
      writeline(file_RESULTS1, v_ILINE1);
      writeline(file_RESULTS2, v_ILINE2);
    end loop;
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --read(file_RESULTS1, dataread1);
     --read(file_RESULTS2, dataread2);
    -- d1 <= dataread1;
     --d2 <= dataread2;
     --aa <= (d1 - d2);
     --writeline(file_RESULTS3, aa);
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    file_close(file_VECTORS1);
    file_close(file_RESULTS1); 
    file_close(file_VECTORS2);
    file_close(file_RESULTS2);
    wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: You say the files contain floats. So why do you read them into integers?

Answer (score 1):

Two key points:

- signals do not get updated until a process suspends
- the **read** procedure is destructive

Remember that signals are not updated until the process suspends, so these should be variables. Signals are for communicating between processes, not for using as storage within a process.

```
    variable dataread1 : real;
    variable dataread2 : real;
```

These and other variables also needed to be **real** not **integer** - you did say that you were wanting to multiply floating point numbers.

The **read** procedure is destructive so these variables are empty by the time you come to write them out:

```
variable v_ILINE1    : line;
variable v_ILINE2     : line;
```

There were one or two other bugs, which I guess were being hidden by these two more important points above. Here is some code that does as you expect:

```
entity file_io is  -- test bench
end file_io;
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;
use STD.textio.all;

architecture test of file_io is
  file file_VECTORS1 : text;
  file file_VECTORS2 : text;
  file file_RESULTS1 : text;
  file file_RESULTS2 : text;
  file file_RESULTS3 : text;
  --signal dataread1 : integer;
  --signal dataread2 : integer;
  --signal aa : integer;
begin
  read_file:
    process    
    variable v_ILINE1    : line;
    variable aa             : real;
    variable v_ILINE2     : line; 
    variable v_ILINE3     : line; 
    variable dataread1 : real;
    variable dataread2 : real;
    variable d1,d2 : real;

    begin
    file_open(file_VECTORS1, "a.txt",  read_mode);
    file_open(file_RESULTS1, "b.txt", write_mode);
    file_open(file_VECTORS2, "c.txt",  read_mode);
    file_open(file_RESULTS2, "d.txt", write_mode);
    file_open(file_RESULTS3, "e.txt", write_mode);

   while not endfile(file_VECTORS1) loop
      readline(file_VECTORS1, v_ILINE1);
      readline(file_VECTORS2, v_ILINE2);
      ---------------------------------------------------------------------
      read(v_ILINE1, dataread1);
      read(v_ILINE2, dataread2);
      d1 := dataread1;
      d2 := dataread2;
      aa := (d1 * d2);
     write(v_ILINE3, aa);
     writeline(file_RESULTS3, v_ILINE3);
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------
      wait for 60 ns;
      write(v_ILINE1,dataread1);
      write(v_ILINE2,dataread2);
      writeline(file_RESULTS1, v_ILINE1);
      writeline(file_RESULTS2, v_ILINE2);
    end loop;
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --read(file_RESULTS1, dataread1);
     --read(file_RESULTS2, dataread2);
    -- d1 <= dataread1;
     --d2 <= dataread2;
     --aa <= (d1 - d2);
     --writeline(file_RESULTS3, aa);
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    file_close(file_VECTORS1);
    file_close(file_RESULTS1); 
    file_close(file_VECTORS2);
    file_close(file_RESULTS2);
    wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/7qz

Comment: It must read: "you did say that you were wanting to multiply **floats**"